# Is there a way to paste the output of a vim command into the buffer?

Tags: vim

Something that I want to do from time to time is paste the output of a vim command into the buffer.  E.g. when I'm editing my vimrc, it'd be nice to be able to fiddle with `statusline` and then be able to just do something akin to

```
"=set statusline?<Enter>p
```

Problem is, that yields

```
E121: Undefined variable: set
E15: Invalid expression: set statusline?
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I figure that this is possible, and that I just don't know enough about the builtin functions and how to use them (I see `expand` used here and there, but have never successfully made it work for me in any context), even though I (think that I) have a pretty solid understanding of normal mode.

Note that this specific example is a little contrived, but I can't think of a better one right now.  For the specific use case above, I could just `":p` to get the whole `set` command that I used during experimentation and then edit to suit, but fairly regularly I run into other cases where I want vim to tell me something and then I want to paste that output somewhere so that I can continue to look at it while continuing with my work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can paste an option setting:

```
"=&statusline<Enter>p
```

I don't know of any way to put the output of an arbitrary command in the buffer, however.

Comment: `redir` the output into a register and then pasting the register would work.  Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: @Herbert Sitz I think you have the best answer to this question. I didn't know about `:redir`.

Comment: Actually, I like the direct paste option you gave, it's something I haven't used and will start using myself . . . Thanks.

Comment: Cool, both for Laurence's answer and Herbert's comment.  Figures that redir is in the grab bag of "various.txt".  :)

Answer (score 5):

The values of settings are stored in variables that are prepended with an `&` symbol.  So the value  that `statusline` is set to can be accessed by referencing `&statusline`.  To insert into a document one way is to use the "expression" register, `<ctrl-R>=`.  To use it enter insert mode and press `<ctrl-R>` and then `=`.  You will see an equals sign in the command line, where you can enter:  `&statusline` and then press `enter`.  This will insert the value into the buffer.

Comment: Thanks- I'm not typically in insert mode when I do this, but it's good to know that settings are referenced with the ampersand.